# Xamarin Slider minimum resets bound value at UWP

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I noticed an undesired behaviour at Xamarins `Slider` at UWP if I use the `Minimum` property. Let's say

```
<Slider Value="{Binding SliderValue}" Maximum="20" Minimum="10"/>
```

is bound to

```
public double SliderValue { get; set; } = 15;
```

This means the initial position of the slider should be exactly in the middle. **But:** During startup, after the Slider got the value (15) it sets the value back to the minimum (10). The slider is now at the minimum left position. Using `Minimum="0"` the slider is not setting its value back and the initial position is like expected. I also tried to change the order of the slider properties at my XAML but the result is still the same.

The problem does not occur if I run the app in Android. Android is not setting the bound value back to the minimum.

Has anybody an idea what could be the problem and / or how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried something like <Slider Maximum="20" Minimum="10" Value="{Binding SliderValue}"/> . I am not sure if it will work, but UWP does reset value when maximum or minimum is changed, so the order might help.

Comment: Yes @IvanIčin I also thought about this behaviour and tried all possible combinations without success.

Comment: Then the only answer I know is to have TwoWay binding and handling the value there. If you see request for slider to get to 10 that doesn't make sense you don't accept it and send propertychanged. I'll post below.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 2**:
If your Max and Min values are constant then Solution 1 is too complicated. I would suggest just binding all three values:

```
<Slider Value="{Binding SliderValue, Mode = TwoWay}" 
Maximum="{Binding Maximum, Mode = OneWay}" 
Minimum="{Binding Minimum, Mode = OneWay}"/>
```

And then when you intialize ViewModel insure to set those values in a proper order (it might be required to do this when you initialize the view in order to work properly):

```
Minimum = 10;
Maximum = 20;
SliderValue = 15;
```

**Solution 1**:
Maybe there are better answers, but I can only suggest to use `TwoWay` binding:

```
<Slider Value="{Binding SliderValue, Mode = TwoWay}" Maximum="20" Minimum="10"/>
```

Then in the ViewModel you handle situation like:

```
private double sliderValue = 15;
public double SliderValue
{
    get
    {
        return sliderValue;
    }
    set
    {
        if (logicToCheckIfValueMakesSense())
        {
            sliderValue = value;
        }
        onPropertyChanged(nameof(SliderValue));
    }
}
```